# Chrome extension to show when I last visited a website

Tags: chrome

I'd like an extension that somehow tells me how many minutes/hours/days it's been since I last visited that website.

This will help me in two ways. To stop my loop of checking Reddit, SE, email, twitter and then repeat, since I'll be confronted by the fact that I visited the website a minute ago. And to realize when I reach a new website, or that I visited it months ago.

Comment: There is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whenx-for-google-search/dgafcidlgmbcehokgdeghmfnbpbfhihh, but it only works for Google searches as far as I can tell